# I can't transform sum to integer in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sum

I have this code to extract sum of column records in mysql

```
<?php
$query = "select sum(sell) from store where sell!=0"; 
$result = $crud->getData($query);
$total_s = implode(" ",$result);
settype($total_s, "integer");?>
<p>Sum now is: <?php var_dump($result);//here my output in html?></p>
<?php //now i want to show in percent from max how much is sell
$maxm = 1000000;
$percent = $total_s / $maxm;
$percent_x = number_format( $percent * 100, 2 );
echo floor($percent_x) . '%';?>
```

**Output in html:**

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["sum(sell)"]=> string(5) "25165" } }
```

In error_log i have the message:

```
Array to string conversion in /home/dancr/public_html/app/out.php on line 36
```

Comment: Where is line 36?

Comment: @DanielCraick: He was asking which line in the code you show is line 36. Not good to answer someone who is trying to help with a smart alec answer.

Comment: $total_s = implode("  ",$result);

Comment: Where is the output coming from? `echo floor($percent_x) . '%';` is the only output statement I can see.

Comment: Also the one echo statement you show in your code is not likely to produce the output you describe.

Comment: Edit your question to show the additional info. Don't put it in a comment.

Comment: I have completed my questions

Comment: @Ken Y-N not helping the answer to that question... very ambiguous answer there, you can see in my code some elements from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't need to trans number string to integer. the issue in your code is the $result_s.

```
<?php
$query = "select sum(sell) from store where sell!=0"; 
$result = $crud->getData($query);
$total_s = $result[0]["sum(sell)"];
$maxm = 1000000;
$percent = $total_s / $maxm;
$percent_x = number_format( $percent * 100, 2 );
echo floor($percent_x) . '%';?>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!